# How to improve Qt + MSVC compile times on Windows 7?

Tags: qt, compiler-construction

The compile times on Windows 7 with Qt, using MSVC10 express and MS SDK 7.1 are longer than they were under Windows XP (still using MSVC10). What's more, when using MinGW my compile times are faster than either MSVC10 scenario.

The CPU seems to only spend 10% max and "Jom" is present.

Would anyone have an idea as to what might cause this? Is there anything I can do to speed up my compile times?

Comment: Are you asking us "On windows 7 my compile times for Qt+MSVC10 are significantly longer than on XP. MinGW on the other hand is faster than both. What might cause this"?

Comment: Yes Bart.... I need help, my CPU only spends 10% max and "jom" is present.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that jom is present. **Please set for the make-command the parameter "-j 8".** Where 8 is just as example - not sure how many threads your machine can fed properly. Because your cpu-usage of ~10% indicates that just a single core is used.

Comment: Please, reword this as an answer. Now it is a question.